# Reporting Services - disable auto loading

Tags: reporting-services, business-intelligence

how to disable report automatic loading? This happens if I have default values for all parameters.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the default values, and setting ShowParameterPrompts="True" on the ReportViewer control? Why do you have default values set, if you don't want the report to use them?

Comment: Defaults will be used in most of cases, but users should be allowed to chose default or change it, I don't want to execute query every time someone starts report.

Comment: Any luck getting this working?

Answer (score 3):

I found a work-around at [Microsoft connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/491145/ssrs-report-viewer-control-prevent-auto-rendering).

First, in the designer set `ShowReportBody= false`;

Then, in code behind:

```
    protected void ReportViewer1_SubmittingParameterValues(object sender, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParametersEventArgs e)
        {
            this.ReportViewer1.ShowReportBody = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `ShowParameterPrompts="True"` on the ReportViewer control. This should disable auto-rendering the report.